# SYSTEM ERROR My Sql php registration form

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a simple registration form for users to sign up to my website.

The first user went in fine, then I tried the second and I get an error when passing the information into the database. "Registration failed because of a system error:".

**Here is the code that it's getting stuck on:**

```
if (empty($errors)) { 
$query = "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, email,
password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
'$email', SHA1('$password'))";      
$results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
if ($results) {
    echo '<h3>Thank you!</h3>
    <p>You have successfully registered.</p>';  
} else {            
    echo '<h3 class="error">System Error</h3>
    <p class="error">Registration failed because of a system
error:</p>'; 
    //DEBUGGING echo '<p class="error">' . 
mysqli_error($conn) . '</p>
    //DEBUGGING <p class="error">Query: ' . $query . '</p>';
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
```

**My form is:**

```
<form action="signup.php" method="post">


<p>First Name: <input type="text" name="first_name" size="30" 
maxlength="30" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) 
echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>" /></p>


<p>Last Name: <input type="text" name="last_name" size="50" 
maxlength="50" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['last_name'])) 
echo $_POST['last_name']; ?>" /></p>


<p>Email Address: <input type="text" name="email" size="60" 
maxlength="60" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) 
echo $_POST['email']; ?>"  /> </p>


<p>Password: <input type="password" name="pass1" size="40" 
maxlength="40" /></p>


<p>Confirm Password: <input type="password" name="pass2" 
size="40" maxlength="40" /></p>


<p><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register" /></p>
</form>
```

Why is the query not working? Why is the data not submitting into the database? My connection says to throw out an error if not database is not connected. As this error doesn't show up, I'm certain the connection is fine.

Edit: full php code..

```
<?php


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

    require_once ('login.php');

    $errors = array();

if (empty($_POST['first_name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your first name.';
} else {
    $firstname = 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['first_name']));
}
if (empty($_POST['last_name'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your last name.';
} else {
    $lastname = 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['last_name']));
}
if (empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your email address.';
} else {
    $email = 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['email']));
}
if (!empty($_POST['pass1'])) {
    if ($_POST['pass1'] != $_POST['pass2']) {
        $errors[] = 'Your passwords did not match.';
    } else {
        $password = 
    mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,trim($_POST['pass1']));
    }
} else {
    $errors[] = 'You forgot to enter your password.';
}

if (empty($errors)) { 
    $query = "INSERT INTO customers (first_name, last_name, email,
    password) VALUES ('$firstname', '$lastname',
    '$email', SHA1('$password'))";      
    $results = @mysqli_query ($conn, $query);
    if ($results) {
        echo '<h3>Thank you!</h3>
        <p>You have successfully registered.</p>';  
    } else {            
        echo '<h3 class="error">System Error</h3>
        <p class="error">Registration failed because of a system
    error:</p>'; 
        //DEBUGGING echo '<p class="error">' . 
    mysqli_error($conn) . '</p>
        //DEBUGGING <p class="error">Query: ' . $query . '</p>';
    } 
    mysqli_close($conn);

    exit();
} else { 
    echo '<h3 class="error">Error</h3>
    <p class="error">The following error(s) occurred:</p>';
    foreach ($errors as $message) { 
        echo "<p class='error'>$message</p>";
    }
    echo '<p>Please try again.</p>';
} 
mysqli_close($conn);
} 
?>
```

Comment: You're probably reading a stoneage tutorial/guide, which simply assumes that magic_quotes is still a thing. You are also utterly vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). As well, `mysqli_error()` RETURNS the error message, it doesn't do output. you have to `echo mysqli_error(...)`

Comment: `'$firstname', '$lastname',
'$email', SHA1('$password'` are defined where? Connection is what? successfully connected how? 2 words: Error reporting.

Comment: I think he is going to be flying SOLO @Fred-ii-

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've updated the post with the full code so you can see connection & defined variables

Comment: Check your Apache/nginx log file for MySQL error. Sometimes could be because you have set the field unique and you are duplicating the field (e.g duplicated first name) and your insert failed.